# What to watch out for when mixing http and https

Tags: http, ssl, https, security, session-cookies

I have a client who really wants to use AdSense which doesn't support ssl.

The project includes a login and eventually credit card purchases.

I wanted to use https for the whole site, but it seems like this won't be possible without getting mixed content warnings because of AdSense.

I plan on forcing secure session cookies and avoiding iframe.

What are some things to watch out for?

Any other advice is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure your session cookies use the **Secure** option. This will instruct the browser that the cookie should only be sent over SSL.

Check this out - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly